# How to install the Red Hat Container Development Kit when behind a corporate webproxy?

Tags: jboss-developer-studio, redhat-containers

When attempting to set up the Red Hat Container Development Kit on Windows behind a corporate web proxy the installer seems to fail to recognise the proxy settings that are configured.

Installer file: devsuite-1.3.0-GA-installer.exe

At the point where you enter your developer.redhat.com credentials it fails with the message "Cannot access developers.redhat.com, please check your internet connection.".

This despite the correct settings in Internet Options and system environment variables for HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY.

The installer page mentioned appears to be a embedded browser window.  I suspect that the underlying platform (node, electron?) is not using the proxy settings that have been configured.

I have not found any log files that are related to this.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Many thanks.

[Edit 5 Jun 2017]

Just tried to install the latest, 1.4.0-GA-2017-05-19-231, version of the Development Suite but suffered the same issue. Also it doesn't look like there is a 'manual install' alternative available on the web site.  Unfortunately the 'Non-Online' (Offline?) version of the installer still requires you to log in to developer.redhat.com which I'd think rather loses the point of being offline.

Comment: That's weird, it looks like this issue should already be fixed: [JBDS-3933](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBDS-3933). It's also  reported as closed in the [1.3 Release Notes](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_development_suite/1.3/html-single/release_notes_and_known_issues/#closed_issues). I reopened that issue with a link to your question.

Comment: In the meantime, you can install CDK 'manually'. See the [CDK Installation Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_container_development_kit/2.4/html-single/installation_guide/#installing_container_development_kit_on_microsoft_windows). It also contains info on how to work with CDK behind a proxy.

Comment: Installer uses request node.js module and those env variables the only way to tell the request module about proxy. I suspect that not all kinds of proxy are supported though (more details are here https://github.com/request/request#proxies).